# Put static page in views content of main layout

Tags: cakephp

In my main layout we got this

```
<div id="myContent">
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?> 
</div>
```

to render the different views on my app. Also, at `/View/Pages/` I have static pages like 'About us', 'Contact', etc.

I would like to know if there is any way to insert the static pages in this place when I do click on the appropriate links.

I think it could be done with JQuery, but the question is if there is any magic in cakePHP to do it. Thanks.

Comment: No magic way, The JsHelper is currently deprecated in 2.x and completely removed in 3.x.  Use jQuery ajax Method to load your views. For views use ajax.ctp Layout

Comment: `if there is any way` - there are many ways, but if you have no ideas how to do what you're asking - look for any example on the web that does do what you want and look at the page markup (the css/js) that makes it possible. E.g. [jquery ui tabs[(https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) is an example of what you're describing. Please do not ask me to clarify further, edit your question if necessary.